# Cant dynamically update the React app using component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The main puprose is to get the info from the tmdb API and load them in the app.

I get the info from the API by saving in the movieRows and with the help of component MovieRow.js to update HTML part but I can't define it properly in the return of function App().

I am struggling a bit with the update of React from class app to function app.

Using the static code in the comments the function works.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import MovieRow from './MovieRow.js'
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery'

function performSearch(){
  console.log("Search function")
  const urlString ="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=Harry&api_key=aca2d915bde9a36a2b60b5b04bb21b7f"
  $.ajax({
    url : urlString,
    success: (searchResults) => {
      console.log("Data fetched succesfully")


      const results = searchResults.results

      var movieRows = []

      results.forEach((movie) => {
        console.log(movie.title)
        const movieRow = <MovieRow movie={movie}/>
        movieRows.push(movieRow)
      })
      console.log(movieRows)
    },
    error: (xhr, status, err) => {
      console.log("error")
    }
  })
}

function App() {

  console.log("This is my inisialiser")


  // const movies = [
  //   {id: 0, poster_src: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg", title: "Batman 1", overview: "Batman is the secret identity of Bruce Wayne.Witnessing the murder of his parents as a child leads..."},
  //   {id: 1, poster_src: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg", title: "Spiderman 2", overview: "Spider-Man centers on student Peter Parker (Tobey Maguire) who, after being bitten by a genetically-altered spider, gains superhuman strength and the spider-like ability to cling to any surface. He vows to use his abilities to fight crime, coming to understand the words of his beloved Uncle Ben: With great power comes great responsibility."},
  //   {id: 3, poster_src: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg", title: "Spiderman 2", overview: "esponsibility."},


  // ]

  // var movieRows = []
  // movies.forEach((movie) => {
  //   console.log(movie.poster_src);
  //   const movieRow=<MovieRow movie={movie}/>
  //   movieRows.push(movieRow)
  // })



  performSearch()




  return (
    <div >
        <table className="titleBar">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img alt="app icon" width="50" src={require("./img/popcorn.svg")} ></img>
              </td>
              <td width="8"></td>
              <td>
                <h1>Movies DB</h1>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <input style={{
          fontSize: 24,
          display: "block",
          width: "99%",
          paddingTop: 8,
          paddingBottom : 8,
          paddingLeft : 22

        }}
        placeholder = "Enter Movie"/>

        {movieRows}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MovieRow.js

```
import React from 'react'

class MovieRow extends React.Component{
    render() {

        return  <table key={this.props.movie.id}>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 <img alt="poster" width="200" src={this.props.movie.poster_src}></img> 
               </td>
               <td width="400">
                  {this.props.movie.title}
                  <p>{this.props.movie.overview}</p>
               </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

    }


}

export default MovieRow
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. *"I am struggling a bit"* isn't really a question; you can just keep using class components.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your problem

```
useEffect(() => {
performSearch()
});
```

You can put `performSearch` function inside of `function App()`

Include `useEffect` using

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

let me know if that helps.